# read on int works in isolation, but how to get it to work in this script?

Tags: haskell

When I try to call read to read an `Int32`, it works in GHCi:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.4.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Data.Int
Prelude Data.Int> let fooInt32 :: Int32; fooInt32 = read "6531"
Prelude Data.Int> :t fooInt32
fooInt32 :: Int32
Prelude Data.Int> fooInt32
6531
```

However, in my app, I get this error (used a wrapped read for better error messages):

```
readInt32.hs:  read error, reading: '6531'
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at /home/brandon/workspace/ProjectGists/Haskell/ReadInt32/readInt32.hs:27:9 in main:Main
```

Here's a self-contained stack script that exemplifies the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-13.14 script
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Data.Int
import           Data.Maybe                       (fromJust, isJust, listToMaybe)
import           Data.String                      (IsString(..))
import           Data.Text                        (Text, pack, splitOn, unpack)
import           Data.Time.Calendar               (Day(..))
import           Data.Time.Clock                  (UTCTime(..))
import           Data.Typeable

newtype CowMark = CowMark {unCowMark :: Int32}
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Typeable)

newtype TableName = TableName {unTableName :: Text}
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

instance IsString TableName where
  fromString str = TableName $ pack str

type CowRecordKey = (TableName, CowMark, UTCTime)

read' :: Read a => String -> a
read' s = case reads s of
  [(x,"")] -> x
  _  -> error $ " read error, reading: '" ++ s ++ "'"

rep2Key :: String -> Maybe CowRecordKey
rep2Key strKey = do
  splList <- return $ splitOn "_" (pack strKey)
  (tblName, mrkStr, timeStr) <- head3 splList
  miInt <- read' (unpack mrkStr)
  timeOut <- read (unpack timeStr)
  return $ (TableName $ tblName, CowMark miInt, timeOut)
  where
    head3 :: [a] -> Maybe (a, a, a)
    head3 list@(_:x2:xs) = do
      mx1 <- listToMaybe list
      mx2 <- listToMaybe (x2:xs)
      mx3 <- listToMaybe xs
      return (mx1, mx2, mx3)
    head3 _ = Nothing

cowRecKey1 :: CowRecordKey
cowRecKey1 = (
    TableName "SxRecord"
  , CowMark 6531
  , UTCTime (ModifiedJulianDay 3234) 0
  )

cowRecKeyStr1 :: String
cowRecKeyStr1 = "SxRecord_6531_1867-09-25 00:00:00"

main = do
  key1 <- return $ rep2Key cowRecKeyStr1
  print key1
```

Not really sure what to make of this. I've also tried annotating `miInt :: Int32` to see if that helped, but it didn't.

Comment: Thank you for the reproducible script - made answering very easy!

Comment: Note that `key1 <- return $ rep2Key cowRecKeyStr1` is just `let key1 = rep2Key cowRecKeyStr1`

Comment: @Cubic amazingly I literally just switched from a tab where I just happened to read this very fact - thanks for pointing it out - it does seem a bit more straightforward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've annotated `read'` in your script with the type expected from it:

```
read' :: String -> Int32
read' s = case reads s of
  [(x,"")] -> x
  _ -> error $ " read error, reading: '" ++ s ++ "'"
```

and immediately got an error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe Int32’
              with actual type ‘Int32’
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: miInt <- read' (unpack mrkStr)
```

Indeed, the `do` block in `rep2Key` is run in the `Maybe` context, so the line

```
miInt <- read' (unpack mrkStr)
```

binds `miInt :: Int32`, but the expression on the right has the type `Maybe Int32`. This is why annotating `miInt` by itself didn't point to the problem.

If you want to fail the parsing (?), change `read'` to return a `Maybe`, like this:

```
read' :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
read' s = case reads s of
  [(x,"")] -> Just x
  _  -> Nothing
```

If you want to keep the `error` behavior (and `read'` signature), or for any other functions that return a pure value, you can change the line in `rep2Key` to

```
let miInt = read' (unpack mrkStr)
```

Here `miInt` is bound to the value from the right hand side without invoking `>>=`, so it'll be expected to be the same type (`Int32` without `Maybe`).

A [Hoogle search](https://www.stackage.org/lts-13.14/hoogle?q=Read%20a%20%3D%3E%20String%20-%3E%20Maybe%20a) shows that this last function exists in Prelude as [Text.Read.readMaybe](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.14/base-4.12.0.0/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe).

Comment: And here I thought I'd become proficient at do-notation. The irony is I was using `readMay` under the hood all along in my actual app (unlike the script above), and evoking error for `Nothing`s. I should probably surface the read returning `Maybe a` as much as possible anyway, except where `read` is demanded.

Comment: I added a way to keep that signature (possibly for something where absolutely no error is possible).

Comment: @bbarker, fret not, this is a subtle one.